# how to handle mongoengine field name with "-"dash in django models.py

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, mongoengine

```
class Patent_document(EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {'collection': 'patent', 'strict': False}
    ucid = StringField(required=True)
    abstract = EmbeddedDocumentField(Abstract)
    description = EmbeddedDocumentField(Description)
    bibliographic-data = EmbeddedDocumentField(Bibliographic_data)
```

My json file in MongoDB has fields that have "-"(dash) in the fields name which will raise an error in the models.py in Django project. How to deal with the special character such as "-" in field name to make it correct?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGsXX.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gsuu.png)

Comment: Please share code as code, not as images